# Use scipy.integrate.quad with Tensorflow

Tags: math, tensorflow, scipy

I am trying to use scipy.integrate.quad with Tensorflow as following.
`time` and `Lambda` are two Tensors with shape (None, 1).

```
def f_t(self, time, Lambda):
    h = Lambda * self.shape * time ** (self.shape - 1)
    S = tf.exp(-1 * Lambda * time ** self.shape)
    return h * S


def left_censoring(self, time, Lambda):
    return tf.map_fn(lambda x: integrate.quad(self.f_t,
                                              0.0,
                                              x[0], # it is not a float before evaluation
                                              args=(x[1],)),
                     tf.concat([time, Lambda], 1))
```

However, I get an error as below:

```
File "J:\Workspace\Distributions.py", line 30, in <lambda>
    args=(x[1],)),
  File "I:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\quadpack.py", line 323, in quad
    points)
  File "I:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\quadpack.py", line 388, in _quad
    return _quadpack._qagse(func,a,b,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit)
TypeError: a float is required
```

X[0] is a Tensor with shape=(). It is not a float value before evaluation. Is it possible to solve the problem? How should I calculate integration in Tensorflow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have at least TensorFlow 1.8.0, you're probably best off using [`tf.contrib.integrate.odeint_fixed()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/integrate/odeint_fixed) like this code (tested):

```py
from __future__ import print_function
import tensorflow as tf

assert tf.VERSION >= "1.8.0", "This code only works with TensorFlow 1.8.0 or later."

def f( y, a ):
    return a * a

x = tf.constant( [ 0.0, 1.0, 2, 3, 4 ], dtype = tf.float32 )

i = tf.contrib.integrate.odeint_fixed( f, 0.0, x, method = "rk4" )

with tf.Session() as sess:
    res = sess.run( i )
    print( res )
```

will output:

> [ 0.          0.33333334  2.6666667   9.         21.333334  ]

properly integrating ***x<sup>2</sup>*** over the intervals of ***[ 0, 0 ]***, ***[ 0, 1 ]***, ***[ 0, 2 ]***, ***[ 0, 3 ]***, and ***[ 0, 4 ]*** as per `x = [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ]` above. (The primitive function of ***x<sup>2</sup>*** is ***⅓ x<sup>3</sup>***, so for example ***4<sup>3</sup> / 3*** = ***64/3*** = ***21 ⅓***.)

---

Otherwise, for earlier TensorFlow versions, here's how to fix your code.

So the main issue is that you have to use [`tf.py_func()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/py_func) to map a Python function ([`scipy.integrate.quad()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html) in this case) on a tensor. [`tf.map_fn()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/map_fn) will map other TensorFlow operations and passes and expects tensors as operands. Therefore `x[ 0 ]` will *never* be a simple float, it will be a scalar tensor and [`scipy.integrate.quad()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html) will not know what to do with that.

You can't completely get rid of [`tf.map_fn()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/map_fn) either, unless you want to manually loop over numpy arrays.

Furthermore, [`scipy.integrate.quad()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html) returns a double (float64), whereas your tensors are float32.

I've simplified your code a lot, because I don't have access to the rest of it and it looks too complicated compared to the core of this question. The following code (tested):

```py
from __future__ import print_function
import tensorflow as tf
from scipy import integrate

def f( a ):
    return a * a

def integrated( f, x ):
    return tf.map_fn( lambda y: tf.py_func( 
               lambda z: integrate.quad( f, 0.0, z )[ 0 ], [ y ], tf.float64 ),
                      x )

x = tf.constant( [ 1.0, 2, 3, 4 ], dtype = tf.float64 )

i = integrated( f, x )

with tf.Session() as sess:
    res = sess.run( i )
    print( res )
```

will also output:

> [ 0.33333333  2.66666667  9.         21.33333333]

Comment: Thanks. I planned to optimize Lambda through learning. however, using integrate.quad seems to cut off the connection in the middle between Variable Lambda and the ultimate training operation. So I get `ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable`

Comment: Sure, happy to help! :) Yes, `integrate.quad()` does not implement a gradient operation. You need to write your own layer with a gradient operation to be able to train through it. The good news is that the derivative of the primitive function is just the original function. :)

Comment: Added code version based on `tf.contrib.integrate.odeint_fixed()`. It's simpler to use, and you might be able to train through it. Please check and comment here if it works.

Comment: Thanks. It is not clear what the y0 and t should be in my case. I guess it is maybe easier if I manually solve the integration and calculate it in real-time.

Comment: It's parametrized similarly to `integrate.quad()`. `y0` is just the value to start from (added constant) and `t` is the variable to integrate by (d **t**).